# how to size rectangles(sized by its inner text) in a column to the largest text block?

Tags: qml

i've got names of different sizes in a Column and want to size the rectangles and the outer item userNameContent based on the the biggest name in the list (without using javascript if possible)

all text rectangles should have the size of the resulting userNameContent.width so that the white gaps are gone, any idea?

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Item
{
    ListModel {
        id: userNames
        ListElement { name: "Short Username" }
        ListElement { name: "Superlong Username that is just too long" }
        ListElement { name: "Medium size Username" }
    }

    id: userNameContent

    width: column.width
    height: column.height

    Column {
        id: column
        spacing: 2
        Repeater {
            model: userNames

            Rectangle{
                color: "lightblue"

                width: theName.contentWidth+20
                //width: userNameContent.width // does not work

                height: 38

                Text{
                    id: theName
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.leftMargin: 10
                    anchors.rightMargin: 10
                    text: model.name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following construction:

```
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: 1
    Repeater {
        model: ["aaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbbb","cccccccc"]
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 30
            width: txt.width + 10
            color: "orange"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Text {
                id: txt
                text: modelData
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works because the `Text` gives it `implicitWidth` based on the text, which then sizes the parent `RowLayout`

Comment: You can't constrain the max width of the Text with this though.

Comment: i don't want to constrain the max width of the text - could be as large as needed

Comment: @GrecKo, Rectange.width will fill the appropriate Text width and so the ColumnLayout will expand to the max of them. Then `Layout.fillWidth: true` will stretch the remaining Texts that are smaller then max.

Comment: My point was that you can't set a width below the maximum width of the Text if you want to with this construct.  
Setting `width` in a Layout is also not recommended.
What you want here is doing `implicitWidth: txt.implicitWidth` in the Rectangle and `anchors.fill: parent` in the `Text`